# In Python, how do I assign a Tkinter button to a piece of code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot work out the code for this and I was wondering if any of you do. I want to assign a button in a tkinter menu to a defined function in another piece of Python code *(Or to have some way of linking them)*. I have tried numerous different websites but I cannot find it easily.

**websites I have tried:**

-https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html

-www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Need to see your code, there are many ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) is the first result I get in google:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback():
    print "click!"

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

As you can see, `command` is used to assign a callback function to run when the user clicks the button.